# angular 2 http get 404

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to replicate the ngPrime datatable demo https://github.com/primefaces/primeng. I'm currently using the latest version of angular (4), along with angular-cli (dev mode). I dropped a json file into my app folder, which is where the service is located. I've tried to mess around with the path, but I can't figure this out. I continue to get a 404.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Car} from './car';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class CarService {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getCarsSmall() {
    return this.http.get('./cars-small.json')
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => <Car[]> res.json().data)
                .then(data => { return data; });
 }
}
```

Here is the src from their site. I did have to import rxjs toPromise and modify the angular core package definition.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Car} from '../domain/car';

@Injectable()
export class CarService {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getCarsSmall() {
    return this.http.get('/showcase/resources/data/cars-small.json')
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => <Car[]> res.json().data)
                .then(data => { return data; });
 }
}
```

Using the complete path solved the issue:

```
return this.http.get('/src/app/cars-small.json')
```

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2](this question and answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch JSON file in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2)

Comment: I've seen other posts like the one you linked to. Do I need to use an observable to retrieve the file? Is the example I provided out of date/incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried to provide the complete path and not relative path... starting from whatever you have (maybe `src`?)

Comment: Should be working, look at the last comment at the bottom from march

Comment: @AJT_82 That was the problem.. Just made a post. Thank you. I guess I need to read up on paths.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason making this change worked-

```
return this.http.get('/src/app/cars-small.json')
```

I don't really understand why I had to go up two directories, when the file is at the same level. I tried app/cars-small.json, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add the folder into webpack package as an asset dir. Then you can request as `http.get('api/config.json')...`

```
  "apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "api",
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],....
```