# Use a JSON file in a component using a service in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a JSON File named "data-emp.json".

```
{
   "empDataSet":[      {
        "Id": 111 , 
        "Name":"Acme",
        "Country":"US"
      },
      {
        "Id": 121, 
        "Name":"Smiths",
        "Country":"UK"
      },
      {
        "Id": 131,
        "Name":"Jones",
        "Country":"US"
      },
      {
        "Id": 141, 
        "Name":"Renault",
        "Country":"FRANCE"
      },
      {
        "Id": 151,
        "Name":"Schneider",
        "Country":"Germany"
      }
    ]
 }
```

Now I have a Component with a Table created in which I want to Render this JSON data. Please tell me how to perform this? I am new to angular 2.

Comment: http://davidlearns.blogspot.in/2016/10/bind-json-data-to-html-table-with.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch JSON file in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2)