# Angular HTTP get json file

Tags: angular, angular-services

Im trying to get a json file using a service with angular 4

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { CONFIG as APP_CONSTANTS } from '../config/config';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SkillstreeService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public getSkills() {
    return this.http.get('data/skillstree.json')
      .map(res => {
        res.json();
      });
  }

}
```

**Component**

```
    import { SkillstreeService } from '../../services/skillstree.service';

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private skillService: SkillstreeService) {
    this.getMageSkill();
  }

      public getMageSkill(): void {
        this.skillService.getSkills().subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
        });
      }
```

but for some reason is sending the 404 to the console, the json file is inside of `src/app/data/skillstree.json` any idea.

Comment: What is the full path for the request for that JSON file in the console?

Comment: put your json file in the assets folder of your project. then your path look like this. 'assets/data/skilllstree.json'.

Comment: this the path that give 404 on the console `http://localhost:4200/app/data/skillstree.json`

Comment: i put the json file in the assets folder but still 404 error

Comment: show your full path now with assets.

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/assests/data/skillstree.json`

Comment: change 'assests' to 'assets'. mistake is there.

Comment: ` ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/skillstree.json" `

Comment: check this angular 4 service ex: https://github.com/Sathishchary/AngularServiceEx

Answer (score 1):

Are you forced to use a JSON file and an HTTP call ?

If not, you can do

**skillstree.ts**

```js
export const SKILLSTREE = [/* Put your JSON here */];
```

**SkillsTreeService**

```js
import { SKILLSTREE } from 'data/skillstree.ts';
import * as SKILLSTREE_JSON from 'data/skillstree.json';

public getSkills() {
  return Observable.of(SKILLSTREE_JSON);
}
```

Comment: any way to do it using http...?

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2

Comment: Why would you use HTTP for not making an HTTP call ? It's a local file, I mean, is there any obligation you have ?

Comment: One possible use case to make an http request to JSON, is if the JSON is a large file that is loaded on a page that doesn't always get used. The json will only get requested if the user hits that page, which may save on some resources.

Comment: Well, that's a good use case, but i still don't see the point of storing a JSON file on a page the user requests, instead of storing it in a database. My guess was that it is a mock of an endpoint, but anyways, even if this use case is true, that doesn't mean you should use HTTP, you can just make an asynchronous function ! You should keep the http service to make http calls, that's what it should be used for.