# Angular 5: read local json file

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I use Angular 5 for my project, i need to get the data from a local json file, i created a service ""JsonDataService" and i put the file in "assets/data" folder, but i can not get the file, igot always the error: Error: [object Object] at viewWrappedDebugError....
Here is the code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class JsonDataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getDepartmentData(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('getDepartmentData');
    const apiUrl = './assets/data/french-regions-departments.json';
    return this.httpClient.get(apiUrl);
      // .map((res: any) => {
      //   const data = res.json();
      //   return data;
      // });
  }
}
```

And the call is here:

```
jsonDataService.getDepartmentData().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

I found some posts about the subject, but none of them works for me.
I can see the content of the json file  from the chrome with the url: *localhost:4200/assets/data/french-regions-departments.json*
Do you have any solution, please?

Comment: can you post the json

Comment: remove the `.` before `./assets/`, if you're in a different URL it will use a relative path instead of searching in `/assets`

Comment: Look at the network request

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2. The solutions work in Online VSCode IDE. I hope it might helps.

Answer (score 0):

The api url should only be

```
const apiUrl = 'assets/data/french-regions-departments.json';
```