# How should I keep static JSON data in my Angular app?

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to make an Angular app which will have multiple pages which will dynamically fetch specific data from static JSON files that I will keep either as data.ts files or in the "assets" folder.

How do I import these JSON data dynamically? i.e., the services should not import the entire range of files at ones. If I click on a category, the service function will import the json file pertaining to that category and show up in the page.

Is there any way to do this? Like a rest API call (without actual web APIs)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43759870/4711754